# How to lower lag/latency when using threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm creating an idle clicker game where the user clicks a button to see a number go up. There are several features within the game that run on a while loop that needs to be run in a seperate thread, however I've experienced lag within the game due to how many threads are present. Is there a module or something I could use that is similar to multithreading but is better for large amounts of threads?

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

#i skipped past a large chunk of code to get to the threads

def auto_click():
    while True:
        click_count += 1
        click_display.config(text=f"clicks:{click_count}")
        time.sleep(2)

auto_click_thread = threading.Thread(name="auto_click", target=auto_click)
auto_click_thread.start()

#checks autoclick purchase button should be active
def autoclick_butt_state():
    if click_count >= 100:
        autoclick_butt.config(state='normal')
    else:
        autoclick_butt.config(state='disabled')

butt_state_thread = threading.Thread(name="autoclick_butt_state", target=autoclick_butt_state)
butt_state_thread.start()

window.mainloop()
```